# Trade, Convert on coinbase using api

Tags: coinbase-api

Using the api at https://developers.coinbase.com/api which is not the coinbase pro. I am able to access my account and see current values for all coins.

On the coinbase website you can sell/buy/convert your crypto, but there is no where in the documentation I can find anything about convert or trade.

What am I missing?

Comment: how can people vote this down without any comments or reason. it is a valid question and coinbase on the developer site says to use stackoverflow.

Comment: You are right... So..Upvoted..

Comment: Did anyone find an answer

Comment: nope, no answer yet. I am assuming that coinbase doesn't support it. So, I guess I will be moving my code over to the pro version.

Comment: Did you have any luck using Pro?

Comment: yes,. the pro version works fine, but it doesn't have convert to other crypto like the basic version (which is something special that coinbase offers).

Comment: what about this endpoint? https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_postconversion